# what is the exact function of acquire and release in python multi thread programming

Tags: python, multithreading, function, locking, release

hi i am new to multi thread programming in **Pyhton** 
as far as i am concerned i the multi thread programming in python the a lock object can lock the process 
of a thread for example in the code below the self.lock.acquire() will set the mode of lock of object to the lock and every other thread which face the self.lock.acquire will stop until the lock object is 
then unlocked and then the code under the self.lock.acquire is executed
for being very precise when you make a lock object its default state is unlocked when it encounter the

self.lock.acquire then its is set to lock and other threads which will face the (self.lock.acquire) then 
because it is set to lock will wait and nothing is done till the lock object is unlocked with self.lock.realese then the self.lock.acquire will set the lock object to lock mode again and then continue until it reaches the realese object 
but the question here if a data is shared between more than two threads 
what is happening exactly 
for example the code below g is shared between three threads 
the only thing i can imagine is that it's not really multi thread because when the realese function in 
add_one is called and we know that the statement self.lock.acquire is blocked in both functions or thread 
of the functions add_two and add_three so what will happen here will it first execute the self.lock.acquire of function add_two  and then because of what we now the function add_three will be locked or what??
so tell me in exact what will happen here

```
from threading import Lock, Thread

lock = Lock()
 g = 0


def add_one():
"""
Just used for demonstration. It’s bad to use the ‘global’
statement in general.
"""

global g
lock.acquire()
g += 1
lock.release()


def add_two():
    global g
    lock.acquire()
    g += 2
    lock.release()

 def add_three():
   global g
   lock.acquire()
   g += 2
   lock.release()


threads = []
for func in [add_one, add_two,add_three]:
threads.append(Thread(target=func))
threads[-1].start()

for thread in threads:
       thread.join()
print(g)
```

Comment: Not quite understand the question. If several threads wait on `lock.acquire()` then when the lock owner executes `lock.release()` only one of the waiters will complete the `lock.acquire` call, others will continue to wait.

Comment: thanks so much what i meant was exactly this because it was confusing when more than one thread are waiting for lock.release() what will happen and i understood by your answer that this would not happen really in parallel time and it has some delay in the time of execution thanks any way i don't know what is under the hood of this concept but for basic understanding i think it was enough thanks any way